# Python Pandas transform multiple csv files in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

it is possible to read and run a data cleaning and transformation pipeline (all with Pandas) on 4 different CSV files in parallel (one per each thread)? RAM would not be a problem because I would read and transform data in chunks, then persist it to a DB. There would not be any shared state between the threads and the threads would not lock on the DB I/O of DataFrame chunks persistance because the inserts will be async using AioPg. I know how to write the code, but I am not very experienced with Python and **I just want to know if the GIL would be relevant/problematic in this case and if it wouldn’t be faster to just do it sequentially.**  Thanks!

Comment: If memory is not relevant than the simplest solution is to use `multiprocessing` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Be aware though that using multiprocessing can result in: 1) duplicated data, i.e. inefficient memory usage 2) overhead due to piping data between processes (this can be very significant!). In your case, i.e. when the "input" to each process is a filename, you should be fine though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a reason to prefer multiprocessing/processPoolExecutor instead of ThreadPoolExecutor in this case? Is it because it bypasses the GIL?

Comment: Also, would there be a problem if I use async functions for I/O bound operations inside the child processes?